# Android SaxParser XMLReader.parse() and InputSource parameter

Tags: android, xml, parsing, saxparser

I am trying to parse my xml file resource with SaxParser. I have created my DataHandler but I don't know how indicate to XmlReader the location of data.xml that is in res/xml/.

What is the correct parameter for InputSource object?

```
    XmlResourceParser parser = getResources().getXml(R.xml.data);       
    SAXParserFactory spf = SAXParserFactory.newInstance();
    SAXParser sp = spf.newSAXParser();
    XMLReader xr = sp.getXMLReader();

    // Create handler to handle XML Tags ( extends DefaultHandler ) 
    DataSaxHandler myXMLHandler = new DataSaxHandler();
    xr.setContentHandler(myXMLHandler);
    //R.xml.data is my xml file
InputSource is=new InputSource(getResources().getXml(R.xml.data));  //getResources... is wrong say Eclipse

    xr.parse(is);
```

Thanks a lot.

Comment: Sorry solved.....http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4680543/changing-url-path-to-local-xml-path-in-android-xml-parser

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that the call to getResources().getXml(int id) is returning a XmlResourceParser, and there is no InputSource constructor that takes an XmlResourceParser.

If you want to stick with the SaxParser, you'll need to open up an InputStream via Resources#openRawResource(int id), and then pass that to the InputSource constructor. You'll also need to move the file to res/raw to use the openRawResource function.